ошибка в парсере на Python
Вкратце пишу свой первый парсер для сайта днс что бы выводить с него данные название видеокарты, подскажите в чём ошибка я просто не понимаю что не так.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import fake_useragent

user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {'user-agent': user}
link = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/'
response = requests.get(link, headers=header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', id="pc-4M8s")

check = block.find('div', class_="product-card-top__name").text

print(check)

вот ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nepro\PycharmProjects\TelegramBot\main.py", line 12, in 
check = block.find('div', class_="product-card-top__name").text
        ^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

<Response [401]>

что значит <Response [401]>

Авито теперь и днс против, сначала договоритесь...

в каком смысле против?

Статус ответа проверяйте. И сам ответ. Видимо там нет такого id

https://www.zenrows.com/blog/dynamic-web-pages-scraping-python#what-is
